# java expression language that can't access 'unsafe' java methods

Tags: java, scripting

I am working on a project where I will let users submit small 'scripts' to the server, and I will execute those scripts.  There are many scripting languages which can be embedded into a Java program, such as mvel, ognl, uel, clojure, rhino javascript, etc., but, as far as I can tell, they all allow script writer to call Java constructors, static methods, etc.

I don't want my users to be able to call anything which I don't provide them (usually through some sort of context object).  Most of their scripts will be arithmetic and logical expressions, in some cases they will need to traverse object properties (getters/setters) or contents of a Map.  I just don't want them to escape the sandbox I provide them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like Java's JSP language (UEL) can do it.  In order to access Java's static methods, they have to be aliased in an xml file--and I don't think non-static methods can be accessed.  I can't confirm this since I can't get glassfish's UEL to work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this through using a [security](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/spec/security-spec.doc1.html) [policy](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just :

```
  //Remember old one
  ClassLoader orginalClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  //Set my classloader
  ClassLoader myClassLoader = new SecureMVELClassLoader();
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myClassLoader);

  System.out.println(MVEL.eval("new com.myapp.insecure.InsecureClass()"));
  //Set back to original classloader
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(orginalClassLoader);
```

and in my classLoader

```
public class SecureMVELClassLoader extends ClassLoader {


 @Override
 public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        //some filter logic here
  if (name.startsWith("com.myapp.insecure.")) throw new ClassNotFoundException();
  return super.loadClass(name);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a functioning sandbox is difficult. What you can do use a custom class loader that only allows lookups to a select few types from its parent.