# Best sandboxed expression language for JVM

Tags: java, expression

I want an expression language that runs on the JVM and includes support for

- math expressions, including operator priority
- string expressions, like substring, etc
- supports named functions

  - this allows me to decorate and control exactly who and what functions can be executed.
- read/write variables that are "typeless" / allow type conversion in a controlled manner.
- does not allow arbitary java scriptlets.

  - it should not be possible to include constructs like new Someclass()
  - cannot execute arbitrary static or otherwise method
- does not allow any OGNL like expressions.
- I only want to functions I map to be available.
- support for control constructs like if this then that is for the moment optional.
- must be embeddable.

This [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051953/java-expression-language-that-cant-access-unsafe-java-methods) is similar, but:

- does not really answer "how" or "what" as does the above,
- allows java object expressions, throwing an exception from a SecurityManager to stop method execution, which is nasty and wrong.
- java object like expressions should be an error at parse time.

[jexel](http://code.google.com/p/jexel/) seem to be closest possible match, but License is a bit horrible (GPL/Commercial).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the scripts to output text, then [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) fit's your constraints quite well.  It runs in an environment where it only has access to the objects you give it, but can do things like basic math.

The [Apache license](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/license.html) is a bit friendlier than GPL too.

Comment: I hate velocity, if i recall its error/exception handling is bad/poor.